# Is it possible to access RFID in Nuxt,JS 2.0 applications?

Tags: nuxt.js, rfid

I am busy developing an PWA using NuxtJS to scan barcodes and 3D barcodes. Would it be possible to also access RFID's?

Is there anybody that can provide me with more detail of a RFID manufacturer or printer of RFID's which I can use as part of my testing.

This is new to me so any advice will be helpful.